# Starting out with an application for Facebook Connect on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, fbconnect

I would like to make a button in order for the user to be able to connect and join a group I have created in Facebook. Is this possible with [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/108)? Is there a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try checking out the newly-updated [Facebook Connect SDK for iOS](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) which has been updated for the Graph API.

You can also check out Ray Wenderlich's series on using the Graph API with the iPhone [starting here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app).