# iOS Auth with Google Cloud Endpoints briefly showing token

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When I use the TicTacToe Google Cloud Endpoint example to auth a user on iOS I briefly see the token displayed on screen before returning to the app.

To show the sign in screen I use:-

```
// present the google sign in view controller
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin
                                                            clientID:kClientId
                                                        clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                    keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                            delegate:self
                                                    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

[self presentViewController:viewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

But before the view controller returns I see the following screen briefly:-

[image]

Is this normal? Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent the extra view displaying an access code when using Google OAuth 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557944/how-to-prevent-the-extra-view-displaying-an-access-code-when-using-google-oauth)