# Google Drive SDK -DrEdit iOS example

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I've loaded the example app, configured the IDs, and get an app that starts nicely and allows me to logon.  Once the logon is complete I get the following message & the app crashes.

Any ideas on what the problem is would be appreciated.

[image: DrEdit error message]

Comment: It seems it's duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557944/how-to-prevent-the-extra-view-displaying-an-access-code-when-using-google-oauth

Comment: Thanks, but I tried a most of their suggestions & they didn't work.  Am beginning to understand the process now.

Answer (score 0):

This message turned out not to crash the program after careful review of the template code.  Message still displays, but then closes to display the tableView.