# Windows Phone 8.1 App stuck after google OAuth

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use Google OAuth 2.0 in windows phone 8.1. All is well but I am getting an extra screen after user consent screen which has a message

> please copy this code , switch to your application and paste it there.

I need the app to resume after the user gives the app the permission to access requested data.
Someone help me figure out why I am getting this extra screen and how I can avoid it an resume into my app again

Answer (score 0):

You should select your app type as "web application", then set your redirect uri.
Please refer to below post.

[How to prevent the extra view displaying an access code when using Google OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557944/how-to-prevent-the-extra-view-displaying-an-access-code-when-using-google-oauth)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a solution on this web page. I changed the start and end uri as provided in ["here"]("https://blog.kulman.sk/implementing-google-login-in-universal-apps/")